# MySQL queries cause: SEVERE: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'

Tags: mysql, apache, jsp, servlets, tomcat6

Whenever I try (My)SQL queries on the sever (the server is in debug mode in Eclipse) I get this error:

```
SEVERE: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
```

Now I can't recall how I got this detail, but I suspect that the following info is relevant:
with `%MyWorkspace%` being some path like `x:\some_path`, this path:

```
%MyWorkspace%\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\rewardy\WEB-INF\lib
```

contains the `mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar` file, that if I'm not wrong has the `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` class that it looks for (am I right ?...)

I use this config: Win7 x64, Eclipse Helios Service Release 2, WAMP Server and Tomcat 6.0.26.

Comment: have you `mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar` in `classpath` or in libs/ on tomcat ?

Comment: Thanks @triclosan, I put it in `Tomcat/lib` and it works now! but for general knowledge: 1. where is `classpath` ? 2. why this certain file had to be there and other files don't ? and how do I know which files have to be there and which don't ?

Comment: review this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> have you mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar in classpath or in libs/ on tomcat ? – triclosan

Thanks @triclosan, I put it in Tomcat/lib and it works now!

Answer (score 1):

You should have to add location of `mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar` via project properties + Java Build Path + Add External Jars (Eclipse IDE)

Comment: I already have it in my project pointing to the right place, but it has [some overlay icon that I don't know what it means](http://img804.imageshack.us/img804/4443/mysqlconnectorjava5113b.png)